# How to label each spike with number in stem plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a series of `nTrials` values stored in an array named `deltaValues1`. I have successfully visualised the distribution as the stem plot with the following code:

```
figure;
[nelements, centers] = hist(deltaValues1);
stem(centers, nelements/nTrials, 'blue');
hold on;
[nelements, centers] = hist(deltaValues2);
stem(centers, nelements/nTrials, 'red');
xlim([0.2 0.55]);
xlabel('RIP Constant $\delta$', 'interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 8);
ylabel('Probability', 'interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 8);
lngd = legend('Our scheme', 'Gaussian');
set(lngd, 'fontsize', 8, 'interpreter','latex', 'Position', [0.45, 0.85, 0.22, 0.01]);
saveTightFigure(gcf, 'delta.pdf');
```

Now, besides the percentage that each value takes up, I also wish to label each stem with its quantity. For example, besides reading value `1` takes up 25% of all the values, I also wish to label out that there are 50 `1`'s in total.

How may I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
text(centers(1),nelements(1)/nTrials,num2str(nelements(1)))
```

If you want color, try

```
text(centers(1),nelements(1)/100,num2str(nelements(1)),'color','red')
```

you may want to adjust the x or y location of the text a bit, and use different variables for the two hist commands (e.g. centers1 and centers2)

Cheers!